# jQuery window resize function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, window-resize, jquery-events

Sorry in advance if this is a minor question, but I'm new to javascript. I'm writing code for a webpage with full-width color backgrounds. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is detect the height of the window, and then make sure that the color block is the size of the window. The function works well on page load.

The problem is when I shrink the window, the div height doesn't change with the window size. I get all sorts of errors, like graphics poking out from behind the div.

I think what I'm missing is a way to detect the height of the content within each div and resize the height accordingly.

You can see how it works at http://pressshoppr.com

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    if(windowH > wrapperH) { 
        $('.fullWidthSectionBG').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
        $('.fullWidthSectionBGFirst').css({'height':($(window).height())-120+'px'});
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowH = $(window).height();
        var wrapperH = $('.fullWidthSectionBG').height();
        var newH = wrapperH + differenceH;
        var truecontentH = $('.fullWidthSection').height();
        if(windowH > truecontentH) {
            $('.fullWidthSectionBG').css('height', (newH)+'px');
            $('.fullWidthSectionBGFirst').css('height', (newH)-120+'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `$(window).height()` in your resize function as well? If it's working fine on the first page load, I don't know why you'd need to do any sort of calculations on the heights when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I totally understand the effect you are going for here, but I would imagine that if your initial bit of code achieves it, all you have to do is reuse exactly that. Treat each resize as if the page had just loaded, and get the results you want, eg:

```
$(function(){

  // encapsulate the code that we know WORKS
  function init() {
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    if(windowH > wrapperH) { 
      $('.fullWidthSectionBG').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
      $('.fullWidthSectionBGFirst').css({'height':($(window).height())-120+'px'});
    }
  }

  // call on page ready
  init()

  // ...and call again whenever the page is resized
  $(window).resize(init)

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and it didn't work -- and then realized that I needed to set up a function to handle orientation change too. Seems to be working, with some extra re-jiggering.